# Where can I get a list of KQL properties available in the Search-Mailbox -SearchQuery in exchange 2010?

Tags: exchange-2010, powershell

Where can I get list of KQL properties available in the `Search-Mailbox -SearchQuery` Commandlet for Exchange 2010.

A few I know of are `subject:`, `body:`, `sentOn:`, but I can't seem to find a comprehensive list anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common ones are listed at
http://help.outlook.com/en-us/140/gg315525.aspx#properties but I doubt that list is comprehensive.

(EDIT)

This is the most comprehensive list I've found, but it's in the Exchange 2013 documentation. Some of the properties may not apply to 2010. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj983804%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx